# Why would "Sending build context to Docker daemon", from PyCharm, fail after 35 MB?

Tags: docker, pycharm, dockerfile, ioexception

I am running a Dockerfile from PyCharm, community edition 2023.1.4. It connects to the Docker daemon on my MacBook through the socket. While building the Docker image, it is "preparing a build context archive" then "Sending build context to Docker daemon". But that process fails after 35MB. The same process works through the Terminal prompt (docker build, docker run commands) so it seems there's something wrong with the PyCharm/Docker combination but no clue what, exactly.

Checked the Dockerfile for typos (one found and fixed), checked memory settings (including Java heapsize for PyCharm), restarted both the Docker engine and Pycharm, checked Stackoverflow and JetBrains support forum. Keep getting: "Failed to deploy ' Dockerfile: Dockerfile': java.io.IOException: com.sun.jna.LastErrorException: [32] Broken pipe